# R: How can I CAST (Reshape) a data frame with character values without getting binary numbers?

Tags: r, reshape

I want to cast this data frame

```
ID    GROUP CHAR_VALUE
```

```
A001  AAA    
A001  BBB   B01
A001  DDD   X99
A002  AAA   A50
A002  FFF   FFF
A003    
A004  FFF   F01
...
```

Into an object like this:

```
ID    AAA    BBB    DDD    FFF    ...
```

```
A001  N/A    B01    X99    N/A    ...
A002  A50    N/A    N/A    FFF
A003  N/A    N/A    N/A    N/A
A004  N/A    N/A    N/A    F01
...
```

With this statement

```
library(reshape)  
cast(tbl, ID ~ GROUP, value = "CHAR_VALUE")
```

I get this binary outcome

```
ID    AAA    BBB    DDD    FFF    ...
```

```
A001  1      1      1      0      ...
A002  1      0      0      1
A003  0      0      0      0
A004  0      0      0      1
...
```

Please note that i have some million records, so performance is important.

Similar question with integers:
[How to use cast on a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743898/how-to-use-cast-on-a-data-frame)

Update:
Its throwing the following error:

```
Using CHAR_VALUE as value column.
Use the value argument to cast to override this choice Aggregation requires fun.
aggregate: length used as default Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...):
2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

Comment: I was able to get the expected output with `dcast` from `reshape2` i.e. `dcast(tbl, ID ~GROUP, value.var = "CHAR_VALUE")`

Comment: Actually, I was able to get the expected output using `cast` from `reshape`.

Comment: Its throwing this error:
`Using CHAR_VALUE as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Aggregation requires fun.aggregate: length used as default
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1`

Comment: Thanks  Dirty Sock Sniffer. Following code does the job:
`reshape(test, idvar= "ID", timevar = "GROUP", direction = "wide")`

Still wondering why `cast` does not work though...